# how to detect html version programmatically

Tags: html, version, doctype

I am looking for the version of html detection mechanism. Is there any solution for this or we can just know by the doc type the html page holds?

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript, you can try `document.doctype`, however as far as HTML version detection (I assume to check features and compatibility), it's usually recommended to look for specific feature detection instead, so something like [**Modernizr**](http://modernizr.com/) is better...